# group by weekly in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I need to group by weekly from oracle SQL , I have below table that contain quantity and which was divided into several categories. I need to get weekly quantity sum for each category.

Source table : quantity_details

```
date (mm/dd/yyyy)   quantity    category
10/1/2018             4            A
10/2/2018             4            B
10/3/2018             5            C
10/4/2018             7            A
10/5/2018             2            A
10/6/2018             2            B
10/7/2018             1            C
10/8/2018             0            C
10/9/2018             8            C
10/10/2018            2            B
10/11/2018            4            D
10/12/2018            6            B
10/13/2018            8            D
10/14/2018            9            C
10/15/2018            11           A
```

Result table should be like below:

```
week start date (dd/mm/yyyy)    category    sum of quantity
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018            A            13
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018            B             6
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018            C             6
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018            D             0
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018            A             0
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018            B             8
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018            C            17
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018            D            12
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018            A            11
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018            B             0
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018            C             0
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018            D             0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use :

```
select to_char(trunc(min(min_Date),'iw'),'dd/mm/yyyy')||' to '
     ||to_char(trunc(min(min_Date),'iw')+6,'dd/mm/yyyy') as week,
    as week,
       category, sum(sum_of_quantity) as sum_of_quantity
  from
(
  select to_char(myDate,'iw') as week, min(myDate) as min_Date, max(myDate) max_Date, 
         category, sum(quantity) as sum_of_quantity
    from quantity_details
   group by to_char(myDate,'iw'), category
) 
group by week, category
order by week, category;

WEEK                     CATEGORY  SUM_OF_QUANTITY
------------------------ --------  ---------------
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018    A            13
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018    B             6
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018    C             6
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018    B             8
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018    C            17
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018    D            12
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018    A            11
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo 1***](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3811f/1)

If you want to include all categories and their quantities as `zero`, even if they're not matched, we should work harder with the contribution of `left join` as :

```
select to_char(trunc(q1.min_Date,'iw'),'dd/mm/yyyy')||' to '
     ||to_char(trunc(q1.min_Date,'iw')+6,'dd/mm/yyyy') as week,
       q1.category,
       nvl(q2.quantity,0) as sum_of_quantity
  from
( 
  select to_char(d1.myDate,'iw') as week, min(d1.myDate) as min_Date,
         max(d1.myDate) max_Date, d2.category
    from quantity_details d1 
   cross join ( select category from quantity_details group by category ) d2
   group by to_char(d1.myDate,'iw'), d2.category
) q1
 left join
(
  select to_char(myDate,'iw') as week, min(myDate) as min_Date, max(myDate) max_Date, 
         category, sum(quantity) as quantity
    from quantity_details
   group by to_char(myDate,'iw'), category
) q2 on ( q1.category = q2.category and q1.week = q2.week )
 order by q1.week, q1.category;

WEEK                     CATEGORY  SUM_OF_QUANTITY
------------------------ --------  ---------------
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018    A            13
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018    B             6
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018    C             6
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018    D             0
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018    A             0
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018    B             8
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018    C            17
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018    D            12
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018    A            11
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018    B             0
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018    C             0
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018    D             0
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo Main***](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3811f/3)

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to need the "zeros" in the result set, maybe these ideas will help: {1} find all possible (unique) combinations of WEEK x CATEGORY (subquery C in the query below) {2} find the sums for each week (subquery S in the query below. {3} LEFT JOIN the 2, so that you get NULL values for weeks that do not have a sum as such. {4} pick the columns you need, and replace the nulls by using CASE.  (Tested with Oracle 11 and 12, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d242952927c13c24bb8c30bf6a3cb98a))

```
select 
  to_char( C.startofweek, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) || ' to ' 
  || to_char( C.startofweek + 6, 'DD/MM/YYYY'  ) as "week from/to"
, C.category
, case 
    when S.sumofweek is null then 0
    else S.sumofweek
  end as "sum of quantity"  
from ( 
  select unique 
    startofweek, category
  from 
    ( select unique trunc( date_, 'w') startofweek from test_ )
  , ( select unique category from test_ ) 
) C left join (
  select unique
    category
  , trunc( date_, 'w') startofweek
  , sum( quantity ) over ( partition by category, trunc( date_, 'w') ) sumofweek
  from test_ 
) S 
  on C.startofweek = S.startofweek and C.category = S.category
order by C.startofweek, C.category 
;
```

Result

```
week from/to              CATEGORY  sum of quantity
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018  A         13
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018  B         6
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018  C         6
01/10/2018 to 07/10/2018  D         0
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018  A         0
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018  B         8
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018  C         17
08/10/2018 to 14/10/2018  D         12
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018  A         11
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018  B         0
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018  C         0
15/10/2018 to 21/10/2018  D         0
```